# How to get prefix string value in Android?

Tags: android, string, prefix

i am working in Android application, Using hasPrefix to get a first string value in iphone, but i didn't know how to do this? please help me

In iphone:

```
Name =@"Thomas edward";
if ([result hasPrefix:Thomas])  
{

}
```

Similarly Android, how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a rather basic Java question. It is very likely that you didn't ask Google.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29), or check the index of the string

```
if(result.startsWith("Thomas")) 
{

}
```